# Invert *only brightness* for monitor

Tags: monitors, color-management

When using notebook in darkness it is more convenient to have the screen mostly black, compared to the default mostly white. The issue of inverting colors was discussed here frequently. One have a choice of either use the `xcalib -i` to invert the colors, or adjust color scheme of the individual OS components. Unfortunately the later option is unavailable for many applications, and is generally painful to set up.

Here is a "typical" Linux Desktop.

[image: A typical Linux Desktop with typical mostly-white color scheme]

Here is an effect of inverse: `xcalib -i`

[image: Simple inverse]

The colors are also inverted, i.e. messed up.

But what about inverting only the brightness channel? We need to first convert the picture into LAB or HSB/V color space, and then **invert only the brightness channel**. This results in correct colors, while enjoying overall darkness and high contrast:

[image: Picture with inversed the brightness channel]

**The question: are there any prospects of achieving this effect with a custom color profile?**